# What's the etymological explanation for the apostrophe in the word ім'я?

Tags: етимологія, орфографія

What's the etymological explanation for the apostrophe in the word **ім'я**?
In English, an apostrophe usually stands for one letter that's dropped.  (i.g. I'm= I Am, didn't = did nOt, etc.)

Comment: In Ukrainian apostrofe means that a sound of previous letter is not «soft». Ukrainian _m_ is always «hard», so there is apostrofe and no etymology.

Comment: Voting aims to improve the quality of the questions. What's the reason for the down-voting in this case? It's better to explain what's wrong with this question together with the down-voting. I really came with a small knowledge about this language and it doesn't seem welcoming to me as a learner of this language.

Comment: I didn't vote down, but here's what would have been the reason for my downvoting in case I did. I googled "apostrophe in Ukrainian" and the first [link](https://www.ukrainianlanguage.org.uk/read/unit20/page20-3.htm) was sufficient to understand that it's got a phonetical function only.

Comment: I agree. Just have to say that based on experience in past, it was really difficult for me to find specific information about some question about Ukrainian language. I'll google in future before I post questions. Thanks.

Comment: @UbiquitousStudent Probably your question got downvoted because you haven't done any research on the topic whatsoever. It's mandatory for questions in the SE network to contain at least a basic amount of research on the topic from the person who asks. Essentially in this instance, you just asked people to google instead of yourself and the biggest problem - there are correct and complete resources on the web that answer your question, e.g. the link provided by P. Vowk.

Comment: @Ubiquitous Student folks probably downvoted your question since it makes absolutely no sense in English. You made a number of errors in it.

Comment: Indeed,  I edited it. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think, you might rely on the wrong assumption that the apostrophe always (and in every language) means [contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(grammar)) (like *let us* → *let's*).

But in Ukrainian the apostrophe usually means that a letter following it should be read as in the beginning of the word ('though sometimes it can be used by other means).

There is a set of Ukrainian letters — *я*, *є*, *ю* — which are read differently depending on their position:

- after a consonant, *я*, *є*, *ю* are read similarly to (Ukrainian) *а*, *е*, *у* but with palatalizing or semipalatalizing the consonant (i.e. /`ʲɑ`/, /`ʲɛ`/, /`ʲu`/);
- in the beginning of the word or after a vowel, *я*, *є*, *ю* are read in the way as the letter combinations *йа*, *йе*, *йу* would be read, i.e. with explicit iotation (/`jɑ`/, /`jɛ`/, /`ju`/; like in *yard*, *Yates*, *Eugene*).

The apostrophe in *ім'я* makes the *я* letter to sound as in the beginning of the word (/`jɑ`/), not as usually after a consonant (/`ʲɑ`/).

<sub>In standard Ukrainian, *м* is never palatalized (except semipalatalization in *мі*). So, one may argue that there's no ambiguity — as we almost never pronounce /`mʲɑ`/ and almost always pronounce /`mjɑ`/, we could "imply" apostrophe between *м* and *я*. Still, in practice we prefer to explicitly put the apostrophe there. Especially that such untypical for standard Ukrainian sound combinations like /`mʲɑ`/ may appear in untypical cases like abbreviations, barbarisms, foreign word transcriptions, etc.</sub>